# Double Hashing Merkle Trees

Tags: hash, sha256, merkle-tree

I under that merkle tree use double hashing (`HA = SHA256(SHA256(Transaction A)`). Curious for answers to the following:

1. Why is there a need to hash it twice?
2. What is the difference between hashing it twice this way or using the hashing method for keys `(RIPEMD(SHA256(P))`
3. Is there any value in hashing more than 2 times?